# What is the correct date format for x-stream-offset for the RabbitMQ Streaming Plugin?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

`Bunny` keeps giving me an error that I believe is being sent back from RabbitMQ that the following strings are invalid date formats:

invalid:

- ISO8601 timestamp string
- milliseconds Integer
- YYYY-MM-DD string
- Unix Time or Epoch Time integer `Time.now.to_i`

valid:

- Integer (gets back the requested message and everything after)
- first (string) (gets back all messages starting from first)
- last (string)
- next (string)

```rb
iso8601 = '2021-08-28T13:40:31-07:00'

opts = {
  exclusive: false,
  manual_ack: true,
  block: true,
  arguments: {
    'x-stream-offset': iso8601
  }
}

queue.subscribe(opts) do |delivery_info, _properties, payload|
  msg = JSON.parse(payload)
  puts msg

  ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag, false)
end
```

i get an error back that says its an invalid stream offset argument

below is the error message from the rake task that I am running it in

```sh
Bunny::PreconditionFailed: PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid arg 'x-stream-offset' for queue 'stream_test' in vhost '/': {invalid_stream_offset_arg,{longstr,<<"2021-08-28T13:40:31-07:00">>}}
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bunny-2.18.0/lib/bunny/channel.rb:2014:in `raise_if_channel_close!'
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bunny-2.18.0/lib/bunny/channel.rb:944:in `basic_consume_with'
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bunny-2.18.0/lib/bunny/queue.rb:191:in `subscribe'
/Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/bin/random/rabbit_mq_stream/lib/stream/lib/read.rb:39:in `read'
/Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/bin/random/rabbit_mq_stream/tasks/read.rake:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

--

below is a working example connecting to rabbitMQ as a stream (without the binary protocol) - the [streaming plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stream.html) is required

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'bunny'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

rabbit_user = 'guest'
rabbit_pass = 'guest'
rabbit_host = 'localhost:5672'

conn = Bunny.new(
  "amqp://#{rabbit_user}:#{rabbit_pass}@#{rabbit_host}",
  client_properties: { connection_name: :stream }
)

conn.start

ch = conn.create_channel(nil, 16)

queue = ch.queue(
  'stream_test',
  durable: true,
  auto_delete: false,
  exclusive: false,
  arguments: {
    'x-queue-type': 'stream',
    'x-max-length-bytes': 500_000_000
  }
)

50000.times do |i|
  queue.publish(JSON.dump({ hello: "world #{i + 1}" }), routing_key: 'stream_test')
  puts "published #{i + 1}"
end

ch.basic_qos(25)

opts = {
  exclusive: false,
  manual_ack: true,
  ## block will make it consume the main IO instead of being a seperate thread
  ## it is not recommended in production
  block: true,
  arguments: {
    'x-stream-offset': 'first'
  }
}

queue.subscribe(opts) do |delivery_info, _properties, payload|
  msg = JSON.parse(payload)
  puts msg

  ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag, false)
end

puts 'done'
sleep 1
conn.close
```

the [Java client examples](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html) show that it should be able to accept a timestamp, but it doesnt appear that I am able to send one, is there an accepted date format?

the Java client Docs for the streaming feature say

> Timestamp - a timestamp value specifying the point in time to attach to the log at. It will clamp to the closest offset, if the timestamp is out of range for the stream it will clamp either the start or end of the log respectively. With AMQP 0.9.1, the timestamp used is POSIX time with an accuracy of one second, that is the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, 1970-01-01.

I can find no examples of what a POSIX timestamp looks like

Answer (score 2):

I wondered the same for the RabbitMQ .NET client. It turns out that there is a `AmqpTimestamp` type.

On the wire it ends up being something like `'T'{(ulong bytes)timestamp}`.

So this worked:

```cs
var streamOffset = new AmqpTimestamp((long)Math.Floor((DateTime.Parse("2023-02-17T08:11:00Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal) - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds));

channel.BasicQos(0, 10, false);
channel.BasicConsume(
    queue: stream,
    autoAck: false,
    consumer: consumer,
    arguments: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "x-stream-offset", streamOffset } });
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the Erlang RabbitMQ source code [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/13e62b0939139293e35406c69376b6c883d1ca97/deps/rabbitmq_amqp1_0/src/rabbit_amqp1_0_outgoing_link.erl), which is not shown in any of the developer docs, it appears that you can get time series data by passing in `{number_of_seconds}s` to get the number of seconds or `{number_of_minutes}m` to get the number of minutes

So, time series data can be formatted as a string - it looks like it does indeed accept some format of time, but again it isnt clear how to get it to work, for the sake of my needs a string value is acceptable

```erlang
%% Erlang Source Code for RabbitMQ
source_filters_to_consumer_args(#'v1_0.source'{filter = {map, KVList}}) ->
    Key = {symbol, <<"rabbitmq:stream-offset-spec">>},
    case lists:keyfind(Key, 1, KVList) of
        {_, {timestamp, Ts}} ->
            [{<<"x-stream-offset">>, timestamp, Ts div 1000}]; %% 0.9.1 uses second based timestamps
        {_, {utf8, Spec}} ->
            [{<<"x-stream-offset">>, longstr, Spec}]; %% next, last, first and "10m" etc
        {_, {_, Offset}} when is_integer(Offset) ->
            [{<<"x-stream-offset">>, long, Offset}]; %% integer offset
        _ ->
            []
    end;
source_filters_to_consumer_args(_Source) ->
    [].
```

The answer in Ruby would be to do the following:

```rb
## float/decimal values are rejected, only accepts whole numbers,
## so you have to round seconds to the nearest whole number
offset = "10s"

opts = {
  exclusive: false,
  manual_ack: true,
  ## block will make it consume the main IO instead of being a seperate thread
  ## it is not recommended in production
  block: true,
  arguments: {
    'x-stream-offset': offset
  }
}

queue.subscribe(opts) do |delivery_info, _properties, payload|
  msg = JSON.parse(payload)
  puts msg

  ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag, false)
end
```